# Unhandled exception on openGL text display

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw text using openGL which will be displayed in a window, over a kinect camera image. The program can draw squares and other shapes fine, but when I call the method to draw the text, it crashes. It seems to be crashing on the

```
glutStrokeCharacter(font, c);
```

Everything else works and when I comment out just this line the program still runs fine. Below  is a code snippet of how I try and draw the text.

```
void Button::DrawSquare(bool selected)
{

    glEnable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH );
    glLineWidth(7);
    if (selected == true) glColor3f(0,1,0);
    else glColor3f((123.0/255.0f),(205/255.0f),(237.0/255.0f));
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2f(X, Y);
        glVertex2f(X+length, Y);
        glVertex2f(X+length, Y+width);
        glVertex2f(X, Y+width);
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(3);
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2f(X, Y);
        glVertex2f(X+length, Y);
        glVertex2f(X+length, Y+width);
        glVertex2f(X, Y+width);
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(4);


    //Start drawing text
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    if (selected == true) glColor3f(0,1,0);
    else glColor3f(1,1,0);
    void *font = GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10;
    glRasterPos2i(this->X+15,this->Y+35);
    string s(*this->trackname); 

    for (string::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        char c = *i;
        glutStrokeCharacter(font, c);// <<-- Line that gives error
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glColor3f(255,255,255);
}
```

The drawing of the squares just before the text works fine.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node78.html) GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10 is an unsupported font for that function. Try using GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN instead.

Comment: I tried using the GLUT_STROKE_MONO_ROMAN and GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN as specified, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: On second thought, you should probably be calling [glutBitmapCharacter](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node76.html#SECTION000111000000000000000) instead of [glutStrokeCharacter](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node78.html#SECTION000113000000000000000)

Comment: Tried that as well, also tried using code from various sources and I keep getting the same error!

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas since I've never used any of those functions, and am not able to spot any other errors in the code you posted.

Comment: Ok, Thanks anyway. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example of how to render text using glutBitmapCharacter:

```
static const std::string text_to_render = "testing 1 2 3 4";

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );  // disable to render text in front of anything else

    glRasterPos2f(0, 0); // center of screen
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    GLvoid * font = GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10;
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    for(char chr : text_to_render)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, chr);
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // re-enable depth test

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The only difference here is that I'm disabling OpenGL's `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and I'm loading the identity matrices after pushing the current matrices.

Let me know if this is of any help.

Comment: No luck. Still getting access violation errors for the lines
"glutBitmapCharacter(font, chr);" and "glutSwapBuffers();". I have put in break points and debugged but when I try and step into the glutBitmapcharacter method it gives the error?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but you do call glutInit() at program start, right? Also, which memory location does the access violation refer to?

Comment: I did call it when I initialize the screen, using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941178/how-to-initialize-glut-with-fake-parameters) and it still gives me the same error --> _Unhandled exception at 0x2af3617a in KinectTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation_.

Comment: Thanks a lot **Tom Knapen**, it was because I had the glutInit in the wrong place and used the "ugly hack" off the site I mentioned above. Your shot in the dark was exactly right, been at this for hours, thanks for the help, so relieved now <(^^,)>